# Did he have birthday this month or not?

Tags: javascript

```
var monthDiff = today.getMonth() - pastdate.getMonth();
var hadBirthdayThisMonth = 
    (today.getMonth() > pastdate.getMonth()) ?
        true : (today.getMonth() < pastdate.getMonth()) ? 
            false : (today.getDate() > pastdate.getDate()) ?
                true : (today.getDate() < pastdate.getDate()) ? false : true;
if (!hadBirthdayThisMonth) monthDiff--;
```

From August 20th 2011 to September 19 2011, the number of days is 60 and it shows 2 months for me, but i want to show it `one` month until his birthday `Sept 20th` comes.

I came up with the above logic, but it does not work.

Comment: Holy nested ternary operator, Batman! O_O

Comment: Also, what's the question? You simply want to know how many months until the next birthday? Or simply whether the birthday was this month or not?

Comment: *"I came up with the above logic, but it does not work."* - I wonder why ;)

Comment: And if he is born on the 31 of the month? When will the end of the month be? And will the persons born on 29 Feb get a birthday every 4 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isBDayInMonth(month, day) {
    var today = new Date(),
        birthDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month - 1, day, 0, 0, 0, 0); /*compose date*/

    return (birthDay.getMonth() - today.getMonth() === 0) ? {
        "msg": "this month",
        "days": parseInt((birthDay.getTime() - today.getTime()) / 864E5, 10) === 0 ? "tomorrow" : parseInt((birthDay.getTime() - today.getTime()) / 864E5, 10) + " days remaining"
    } : (birthDay.getMonth() - today.getMonth() === 1) ? {
        "msg": "next month",
        "days": parseInt((birthDay.getTime() - today.getTime()) / 864E5, 10) + " days remaining"
    } : (today.getMonth() > birthDay.getMonth()) ? {
        "msg": "in " + ((11 - today.getMonth()) + birthDay.getMonth()) + " months",
        "days": "many days remaining"
    } : {
        "msg": "in " + (birthDay.getMonth() - today.getMonth()) + " months",
        "days": "many days remaining"
    };
}
```

Works in all the cases - just returning an object with 2 props:

- info about month
- info about the days, number shows only if the birthday is in the next month

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PEveu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

> From August 20th 2011 to September 19 2011, the number of days is 60

I think it is generally considered to be 30, or 31 if the 20th is included.

> and it shows 2 months for me,

"it"? It's only one month.

There are many ways to determine if one date is within one month of another, e.g.

```
function withinOneMonth(d0, d1) {

  // Copy dates so don't affect originals
  var t0 = new Date(d0);
  var t1 = new Date(d1);
  var t;

  // Get sense right
  if (t0 > t1) {
    t = t0;
    t0 = t1;
    t1 = t;
  }

  // Check if within moth
  t0.setMonth(t0.getMonth() + 1);

  // Not inclusive. To make inclusive, use >=
  return t0 > t1;
}
```